# I have problem with install juju controler on MAAS node

Tags: juju, maas

I am installing juju on MAAS node, i am using this guide https://oxynets.wordpress.com/2017/01/31/ubuntu-server-install-ubuntu-maas-juju-and-openstack-on-ubuntu-16-04-1lts-server-edition-part-1/
but in the step 5 when use **juju bootstrap maaslab maaslab-controller** comand this report the next error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk35c.png)

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.

For some reason, the memory constraint (mem 3584) didn't want to be met.  I forced it lower, and to install on a particular machine, like this:

```
juju bootstrap MaasServer2 --to jujuTest.maas --bootstrap-constraints="mem=3G"
```